# what is the API for Conversation history folder in outlook?

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create python script to read and process conversation history folder in outlook.

Where can I get a Conversation history API for it?

`outlook.GetDefaultFolder()` does not have conversation history index as per the Microsoft website.

Is there any other approach to read the items in a conversation history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there but its listed as "Conversation Action Settings".

Try running the following python script and see if it comes up for you.

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch as Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

class Dummy():
    def __init__(self, outlook_object):
        self._obj = outlook_object

    def items(self):
        array_size = self._obj.Count
        for item_index in range(1,array_size+1):
            yield (item_index, self._obj[item_index])

    def prop(self):
        return sorted( self._obj._prop_map_get_.keys() )

for _, folder in Dummy(mapi.Folders).items():
    print(folder.Name)
    for inx,subfolder in Dummy(folder.Folders).items():
        print(subfolder.Name)
```

Comment: being new to python above looks gibberish to me. Could you please explain a bit. @chumbaloo

Comment: No problems. 
The Dummy class just creates an iterator to iterate over the items in mapi i.e. the folders).

The outer part of the nested loop, loops through the iterator items (i.e. folders) and prints them. The inner part of the nested loop, loops through the subfolders and prints them.

So for myself, my folders are essentially my "email accounts", and the subfolders are the subfolders under those email accounts. 

Here is the output for me:
Tasks
Sent Items
Quick Step Settings
...
Journal,
Inbox,
Drafts,
Deleted Items,
Conversation Action Settings,
Contacts,
...